# How do I defeat the default action of a query variable on home page redirects to posts page

Tags: rewrite-rules, query-variable

I am using a query variable to pass some information around the site. It works fine, except that Wordpress is operating some rewrite in the background.

In particular, on the (static) home page adding a query variable redirects to the Posts page.

I have found that this is some kind of 'side-effect'(or perhaps intended effect) of defining the query-variable through the `query_vars` hook. Removing the definition removes this behaviour but **still leaves the parameter available** through `get_query_var()`

I'd like to understand more about this.

What are the issues associated with **not** defining the query variable?

What advantage is there to defining the query variable if it works without definition?

My hook;

```
function region_query_var( $qvars ) {
  $qvars[] = 'filter-region';
  return $qvars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'region_query_var' );
```

Comment: Can you describe what the actual side effect is? What name are you using for the paramater? Is it one of the [reserved terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms)?

Comment: The term is 'filter-region' so https://example.com?filter-region=foo

Not a reserved term (most but by no means all are obvious so that reference is useful.

The exact effect is that if the query variable is defined  (I've inserted my hook above) then the behviours of the URL is to display a selection of posts and put the class 'blog' into the body classlist.

Comment: Is filter-region also the name of a taxonomy?

Comment: no, I was using "region" but that is the name of a taxonomy and that did cause issues so I changed it to "filter-region". I have a feeling that what is happening is that using query variables is defeating the normal loading of the static front page and loading index.php instead. As I said, it's more about understanding what underlies these things.

Comment: As far as I’m aware the behaviour you’re describing shouldn’t happen. Are you also using pre_get_posts to do something with the query variable?